# Adjust height of View

Tags: objective-c, iphone, ios8

I have a table and below this their is bottomView . My aim is move up bottomview when keyboard up. but when we tweak keyboard this method call my bottom view more upward. I am stuck

```
- (void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{    
        NSDictionary* info = [aNotification userInfo];
        CGSize kbSize = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;
    keyBoadSize =kbSize.height;

        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2f animations:^{
        CGRect frame=bottomView.frame;
        keyBoardHeight = keyBoadSize;


        frame.origin.y -=keyBoadSize;
          bottomView.frame=frame;
        frame = tableViews.frame;
        frame.size.height -= keyBoardHeight;
        tableViews.frame = frame;



}
```

I am also using

```
- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView
{
    CGFloat fixedWidth = textView.frame.size.width;
    CGSize newSize = [textView sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(fixedWidth, MAXFLOAT)];
    CGRect newFrame = textView.frame;
    newFrame.size = CGSizeMake(fmaxf(newSize.width, fixedWidth), newSize.height);
    textView.frame = newFrame;
    CGRect frame1 = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds;
    bottomView.frame=CGRectMake(0, frame1.size.height-keyBoardHeight-20-newSize.height, self.view.frame.size.width, newSize.height+50);



}
```

Comment: @ElCaptain I am not using constraint

Comment: You need to set the `contentInset` of your tableview correctly. Set its height component to the height of the keyboard.

Comment: @Abhinav Please help

Answer (score 0):

You need to first add space in your table view to allow scrolling:

```
[self.tableView setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, keyBoardheight, 0.0)];
```

Then animate Y position of your custom bottom view.

As a side note, in your sample code `keyBoadSize` is misleading. It should be `keyBoardheight`.

PS: Don't forget to reset the scrolling space when keyboard is dismissing like this: `[self.tableView setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsZero];`.

Comment: IT WORK WELL FOR TABLE VIEW  but not for bottom view

Comment: Custom view is part of your table view. Unless you won't add space in your scrollable content, view won't scroll properly. If you read my response, I am still asking you to animate Y position of your custom bottom view.